# FastCGI concurrency. How IIS creates new processes?

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

In order to test how IIS creates new FastCGI processes I created a simple example.

1. test.php

```
<?php
echo 'start:' . date("d.m.Y H:i:s", time());
sleep(10);
echo ';finish: ' . date("d.m.Y H:i:s", time());
?>
```

2. start.bat

```
@echo off
set url=http://localhost:8093/test.php
for /l %%i in (1,1,20) do (
    start %url%
)
```

Bat file executes test.php with a sleep function 20 times almost simultaneously. But resuls are a bit unexpected.

```
pid: 11716;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:16;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:26
pid: 11716;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:26;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:36

pid: 11716;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:36;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:46
pid: 3660;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:36;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:46
pid: 1316;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:36;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:46
pid: 14788;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:36;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:46
pid: 15752;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:37;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:47
pid: 8836;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:37;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:47

pid: 11716;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:46;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:56
pid: 3660;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:46;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:56
pid: 1316;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:46;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:56
pid: 14788;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:46;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:56
pid: 15752;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:47;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:57
pid: 8836;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:47;finish: 24.12.2020 12:18:57

pid: 11716;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:56;finish: 24.12.2020 12:19:06
pid: 3660;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:56;finish: 24.12.2020 12:19:06
pid: 1316;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:56;finish: 24.12.2020 12:19:06
pid: 14788;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:56;finish: 24.12.2020 12:19:06
pid: 15752;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:57;finish: 24.12.2020 12:19:07
pid: 8836;start: 24.12.2020 12:18:57;finish: 24.12.2020 12:19:07
```

So, initially IIS created only one process - 11716, which executed twice, then IIS created another 5 processes and each of these 6 processes was executed 3 times. I set parameters MaxInstances=200,
and threadPool parameter MaxProcesses=100 before the test.

Could anybody please explain this behaviour and how to configure IIS so requests run in parallel ?

Comment: The actual scheduling logic is not documented by Microsoft, and there is no setting to change what you observed either. BTW, keep in mind Microsoft is no longer active in PHP support, https://news-web.php.net/php.internals/110907

Comment: I tested the process execution order according to your settings, as you described. However, I found that these 6 processes are not created at the same time, IIS first creates a process, the process is executed twice (not at the same time), and then creates 5 processes. So these 6 processes are not created and executed at the same time.

Comment: So I think this is a built-in mechanism of IIS, it will automatically select the optimal number of processes and execution method. And 6 processes is the maximum number of processes that IIS can create. Because when I set the max instance to more than 6, only 6 processes are always created.

Comment: I continued to test this example using different Web-servers (Apache and Nginx), also created a simple ASP. NET example. And all results were the same. So, I think  that Google Chrome is responsible for this behaviour and creates this delay when there are a lot of tabs with the same URL. Also, this is a wrong approach to do load testing. Eventually I downloaded JMeter and performed examples with 5-20  processes and it worked in parallel. Thank you, for you replies.

Comment: I'm very sorry, my previous thoughts were wrong, and I hope it did not mislead you. In fact, IIS created 6 processes not because it automatically selects the best mechanism, but the maximum number of Google Chrome connections is only 6. When I switched IE, IIS created more processes. Therefore, the number of processes is limited by MaxInstance as well as [browser limitations](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html).

Comment: As for the execution order of these processes, it involves the lower-level algorithms of IIS and Windows, which is not recorded in the Microsoft documentation.